# C++ builder - Label caption does not change when it is located on CategoryPanel

Tags: c++, c++builder, caption, redraw

I have a Label on CategoryPanel and trying to change it's caption onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave events

```
  void __fastcall TForm1::Label1MouseEnter(TObject *Sender)
  {
     Label1->Caption="On";
  }

  void __fastcall TForm1::Label1MouseLeave(TObject *Sender)
  {
     Label1->Caption="Off";
  }
```

but label caption does not redraw. Both texts are shown simultaneously ("On" and "Off"). I tried to use

```
    Label1->Repaint();
```

but as it seems it does not work.

Comment: Have you tried `Invalidate()` or `Update()` instead of `Repaint()`? Have you tried calling them on the `TCategoryPanel` instead of the `TLabel`?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, I have tried calling both Invalidate() and Update() but without luck. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Set the CategoryPanel's `DoubleBuffered` property to true, then updating the Label will draw correctly without having to trigger repaints manually.

Comment: Thank you very much Remy. It works! This is the right answer.